# OkHttpClient skip proxies requiring authentication

Tags: java, proxy, okhttp

I am using OkHttp3 together with the proxy-vole library to automatically select the proxy to use. In my case there are 4 possible proxies available using automatic configuration (all the same concept, just load balancing). However it seems only one of them is capable to be used without explicit authentication.

I checked the source of OkHttp and it seems to have a concept of falling back to different proxies if a list i returned from the proxy selector. However this only seems to happen if the connection fails, not if the proxy asks for authentication. Is there a way to tell OkHttp that it should ignore this exception and just move on to the next proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything built in for this.